# SQL Reporting Services Boolean Parameter (True/False/All(?))

Tags: boolean, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that works with boolean parameter. I would like to add a third option to show all the records on the report. Both true and false. The concept is that the dropdown will include three options (All,True,False).

Is there a way to acheive that?

Thanks,

-Y

Answer (score 2):

Set the dataset filter to something like this:

I have 3 available values for `@parmTRUEFALSE`

```
False = False
True = True
All Records = (Null)

=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!parmTRUEFALSE.Value), ObjectFieldName.Value, Parameters!parmTRUEFALSE.Value)
```

If the user selects All Records... the filter uses `ObjectFieldName.Value` and returns all records because `@parmTRUEFALSE = (Null) / IsNothing`

Answer (score 1):

**Select Allow multiple values:**

[image]

**Then add the desired values:**

[image]

**Then add a new filter and convert the field value to String:**

[image]

**Then select the IN operator:**

[image]