# ssrs specific value true/false/all

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a parameter @ResourceSatus, which should has 3 options: true/false/all.
It works well with true/false, but when i add "all" it doesn't show anything. I use filter as explained in this post: [SQL Reporting Services Boolean Parameter (True/False/All(?))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621111/sql-reporting-services-boolean-parameter-true-false-all)

I don't understand what should put for ObjectFieldName.Value. Appriciated for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!parmTRUEFALSE.Value), ObjectFieldName.Value, Parameters!parmTRUEFALSE.Value)` is the code from the other question.

`ObjectFieldName` is just the name of the object you would want to display if `IsNothing(Parameters!parmTRUEFALSE.Value)` equates to true. If you're pulling from a database field named `Example`, `ObjectFieldName` would be replaced with `Fields!FirstDegreeYear.Value`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me, i want to display much information from database. i make the query in the dataset, then what should i put for ObjectFieldName??

Comment: @user3752500 You would but the name of the database column be displayed.